# creating a single colored point over a normal distribution in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution

I was looking to plot a normal distribution in ggplot, and at the suggestion of @nrussell I have used

`ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = dnorm)`

[image]

I am wondering if there is any way to, within the context of `stat_function`, layer a single colored point directly onto the curve. For example, if I wanted to put a dot where the x axis is marked 2.

I have experimented with `geom_point` but this appears to be better at creating scatterplots: I can't seem to pipe in the aesthetics from the `stat_function` for the layer be created.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a way to do this with another `stat_function` layer, but after playing around with it for a few minutes it seemed easier to just use `geom_point` to add a single point:

```
library(ggplot2)
##
ggplot(
  data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), 
  aes(x))+ 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm)+
  geom_point(
    data=data.frame(x=2,y=dnorm(2)),
    aes(x,y),
    color="red",
    size=4)
##
```

[image]

Comment: nrussell is the best thing that has happened to me today. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `annotate`, and just specify `x = 2, y = dnorm(2)`. Rather than trying to pull info out of `stat_function()`

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm) +
  annotate(geom = "point", x = 2, y = dnorm(2), color = "red")
```

Annotate is best for small additions. To use `geom_point()` you'd want to define a new data.frame, good if you wanted to plot more than one point.