# how to numerically calculate the asymptote in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, complexity-theory

This question  is derived from that
[calculate lim function with plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022437/calculate-lim-function-with-plot-in-r).
 Maurits Evers provided working solution,
but i need result of  calculating the asymptote to be marked in plot as red point.

so here lim
 `(\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x}{x - 1} - 2\right)`
)

[image]

The result of this function=-1

how the result of this function(x / (x - 1) - 2) calculate in R? , and  then display it on this plot

```
my_func <- function(x) x / (x - 1) - 2

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun = my_func, aes(colour = "Function")) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = -1, colour = "Asymptote")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("Asymptote" = "blue", "Function" = "orange")) + 
    xlim(-10, 10) +
    theme_minimal()
```

as red point.

Comment: The title of your question is clear, but then it gets confusing. Are you *only* looking for some `fun` that `fun(my_func)` would return `-1` in this case? So that then `yintercept = fun(my_func)` and we're done. Or do you somehow want to plot it as a *point*? If so, what do you mean? Point (10,-1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since R conforms to international standards, it returns NaN for Inf/(Inf-1) so you need to supply a very large number to the function:

```
 lim <- my_func(exp(100))
> lim
[1] -1
```

The number could even have been higher. The overflow occurs someplace between exp(600) and exp(800):

```
> exp(600)
[1] 3.77302e+260
> exp(800)
[1] Inf
```

Comment: Learn to search for questions that are likely to have been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683698/creating-a-single-colored-point-over-a-normal-distribution-in-ggplot